# Jumplist program icon not updating

Tags: c#, visual-studio, icons

I've changed my application's icon via the Application tab of its properties. The taskbar icon and "pin to taskbar" icon both update, but when you right-click, the old icon is shown in the jumplist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear Windows icon cache.

https://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting

Comment: Ah yep, I forgot about this question - nuking the icon cache (IconCache.db in appdata) was the answer. I still needed a reboot though.